# Read file content using angular-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using angular-file-upload module for file uploading in angularjs project. I want to read file content using FileUploader and display in textarea.

Please suggest how i can achieve this

Thanks in advance

**Controller**

```
'use strict';


angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload'])


.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'rest/fileupload'
    });
    $scope.filecontent;
    // CALLBACKS

    uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
        console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
    };
    uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
        console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
    };
    uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
        console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
    };
    uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
        console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
    };
    uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
        console.info('onCompleteAll');
    };

    console.info('uploader', uploader);
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="AppController" nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader">
   <div class="well my-drop-zone" nv-file-over="" uploader="uploader">Base drop zone</div>
</body>
```

i want to take file content in $scope.filecontent variable

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some codes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: @lin I added the code

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks werent working right for some reason so instead once 'upload' was clicked I had a function run in my controller that logged the file content and then ran the item.upload() function.. I attached a basic sample below.

```js
someFxn(item) {
  console.log(item);
        
  item.upload();
}
```

```html
<md-button class="md-blue" ng-click="$ctrl.someFxn(item)" ng-disabled="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
Upload
</md-button>
```